# why the left shift operation does not work

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I have the following code, where we try to left shift certain bits of a value:

```
int main()
{
   unsigned long mvb = 1;

   mvb << 8;
   printf("The shift value is %u\n", mvb);

   mvb << 56;
   printf("The shift value is %u\n", mvb);
}
```

but the result for all those two operation are both `1`, what is the reason, and how use it correctly?

Comment: Seems like you meant `<<=`

Comment: And read the `printf` manpage. You are using the wrong type specifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign it back to mvb after shifting like:

```
mvb = mvb << 8;
```

Comment: @ratzip Operator itself wont change the original value , you have to assign it .

Answer (score 4):

`%u` is the wrong format specifier for an `unsigned long`, so the program behaviour is undefined. Use `%lu` instead.

Note that you're not actually changing the value of `mvb`: the `printf` calls are operating on the original value of `mvb`.

Writing `mvb <<= 8` is the fix (this is using the bitwise left shift assigment operator), but be careful not to apply a shift beyond the number of bits in your type, as that is *also* undefined behaviour in C. For the avoidance of doubt, the undefined behaviour only results if you shift by too many bits *at once*: the subsequent shift of `mvb <<= 56` is fine for a 64 bit type, but `mvb <<= (8 + 56)` would **not** be.

Comment: And you completely missed the point. Hint: `mvb << 8` doesn't assign to `mvb`.

Comment: We'll publish jointly! Amended. Fortunately the UB point *is* important so I'll leave the answer in.

Comment: Another neat fact: `a << 50 << 50` is well-defined for all `a` if `a` has an unsigned type with 64 bits, but `a << 100` is not.